# error code 1048 column 'value' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have SP for update the data into new data with this query, so basically every id have own value for own rule_id, and this SP is to update the data with the new one from the SP

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_discount_campaign_advanced2`(IN DiscountCampaignId INT(10),
    IN rule_percentage VARCHAR(255),
    IN rule_quota_daily_max VARCHAR(255),
    IN rule_discount_daily VARCHAR(255),
    IN rule_discount_weekly VARCHAR (255),
    IN rule_discount_monthly VARCHAR(255),
    IN rule_spesific_payment_method VARCHAR(255),
    IN rule_spesific_cc_operator VARCHAR(255),
    IN allow_other_product VARCHAR(255)
)
proc:
BEGIN
    DECLARE is_discount_campaign_id INT(10);
    DECLARE is_rule_percentage VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_rule_quota_daily_max VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_rule_discount_daily VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_rule_discount_weekly VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_rule_discount_monthly VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_rule_spesific_payment_method VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_rule_spesific_cc_operator VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE is_allow_other_product VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE param_1_message TEXT;
    SET @is_discount_campaign_id = DiscountCampaignId;
    SET @is_rule_percentage = rule_percentage;
    SET @is_rule_quota_daily_max = rule_quota_daily_max;
    SET @is_rule_discount_daily = rule_discount_daily;
    SET @is_rule_discount_weekly = rule_discount_weekly;
    SET @is_rule_discount_monthly = rule_discount_monthly;
    SET @is_rule_spesific_payment_method = rule_spesific_payment_method;
    SET @is_rule_spesific_cc_operator = rule_spesific_cc_operator;
    SET @is_allow_other_product = allow_other_product;
SELECT CONVERT( CONCAT('Maaf, ID discount_campaign tidak bisa \'0\'') USING UTF8) INTO param_1_message;

    IF (DiscountCampaignId = 0) THEN
        SELECT param_1_message AS message;
        LEAVE proc;
            END IF;
    
    IF (DiscountCampaignId != 0) THEN
    
        INSERT INTO discount_campaign_advanced (id,discount_campaign_id,
          discount_advanced_rules_id, value, createdAt, status, updatedAt)
        select *, CASE WHEN 
        unitData.id is NULL THEN NULL ELSE NOW() END as updatedAt from (SELECT dca.id  , DiscountCampaignId, dar.id as dar_id1, CASE WHEN dar.id = 1
        THEN @is_rule_percentage WHEN dar.id = 2 THEN @is_rule_quota_daily_max
        WHEN dar.id = 3 THEN @is_rule_discount_daily WHEN dar.id = 4 
        THEN @is_rule_discount_weekly  WHEN dar.id = 5 THEN @is_rule_discount_monthly
        WHEN dar.id = 6 THEN @is_rule_spesific_payment_method WHEN dar.id = 7
        THEN @is_rule_spesific_cc_operator END, coalesce(dca.createdAt, NOW()), CASE  when (dar.id = 1
        and @is_rule_percentage != '0') THEN 1 WHEN (dar.id = 2 and
        @is_rule_quota_daily_max != '0') THEN 1 WHEN 
        (dar.id = 3 and @is_rule_discount_daily != '0') THEN 1 WHEN (dar.id = 4 and
        @is_rule_discount_weekly != '0') THEN 1
        WHEN (dar.id = 5 AND @is_rule_discount_monthly != '0') THEN 1 WHEN (dar.id = 6 
        AND @is_rule_spesific_payment_method != '0')
        THEN 1 WHEN (dar.id = 7 AND @is_rule_spesific_cc_operator != '0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bb
       FROM
    discount_advanced_rules dar
        LEFT JOIN
    discount_campaign_advanced dca ON dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = dar.id
 and dca.discount_campaign_id = DiscountCampaignId) as unitData
        WHERE unitData.bb = 1
        
        UNION 
        
        SELECT dca.id, DiscountCampaignId, dca.discount_advanced_rules_id, CASE  WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 1
        THEN @is_rule_percentage WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 2 THEN @is_rule_quota_daily_max
        WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 3 THEN @is_rule_discount_daily WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 4 
        THEN @is_rule_discount_weekly  WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 5 THEN @is_rule_discount_monthly
        WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 6 THEN @is_rule_spesific_payment_method WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 7
        THEN @is_rule_spesific_cc_operator END, coalesce(dca.createdAt, NOW()), CASE  when (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 1
        and @is_rule_percentage != '0') THEN 1 WHEN (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 2 and
        @is_rule_quota_daily_max != '0') THEN 1 WHEN 
        (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 3 and @is_rule_discount_daily != '0')
        THEN 1 WHEN (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 4 and
        @is_rule_discount_weekly != '0') THEN 1
        WHEN (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 5
        AND @is_rule_discount_monthly != '0') THEN 1 WHEN (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 6 
        AND @is_rule_spesific_payment_method != '0')
        THEN 1 WHEN (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 7 AND @is_rule_spesific_cc_operator != '0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bb,
        NOW()
        FROM discount_campaign_advanced dca
        WHERE dca.discount_campaign_id = DiscountCampaignId
        
        on duplicate key update id = values(id), discount_campaign_id = values(discount_campaign_id),
          discount_advanced_rules_id = values(discount_advanced_rules_id), value = values(value),  
          createdAt = values(createdAt), status = values(status), updatedAt = values(updatedAt);
          
          END IF;
          
          
     IF (allow_other_product != 0) THEN
      INSERT INTO discount_campaign_advanced (id,discount_campaign_id,
           discount_advanced_rules_id, value, createdAt, status, updatedAt)
         select *, CASE WHEN 
         unitData.id is NULL THEN NULL ELSE NOW() END as updatedAt from (SELECT dca.id  , DiscountCampaignId, dar.id as dar_id1, CASE WHEN dar.id = 8
         THEN @is_allow_other_product END, coalesce(dca.createdAt, NOW()), CASE  when (dar.id = 8
         and @is_allow_other_product != '0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bb
        FROM
     discount_advanced_rules dar
        LEFT JOIN
     discount_campaign_advanced dca ON dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = dar.id
  and dca.discount_campaign_id = DiscountCampaignId) as unitData
         WHERE unitData.bb = 1
        
        UNION 
        
         SELECT dca.id, DiscountCampaignId, dca.discount_advanced_rules_id, CASE WHEN dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 8 THEN @is_allow_other_product  END, coalesce(dca.createdAt, NOW()), CASE  when (dca.discount_advanced_rules_id = 8
         and @is_allow_other_product != '0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bb,
         NOW()
         FROM discount_campaign_advanced dca
         WHERE dca.discount_campaign_id = DiscountCampaignId
        
         on duplicate key update id = values(id), discount_campaign_id = values(discount_campaign_id),
           discount_advanced_rules_id = values(discount_advanced_rules_id), value = values(value),  
           createdAt = values(createdAt), status = values(status), updatedAt = values(updatedAt);
          
           END IF;
END
```

but idk why when i call this SP call brambang_uom.update_discount_campaign_advanced2(2757, '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '9');

it returns Error Code: 1048. Column 'value' cannot be null`, where my wrong at?

Comment: Firstly - replace asterisks in all `SELECT *` with definite columns lists. Avoid asterisks at all - except COUNT(*).